# pass argument to redux action from component while it's rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to get a list of comments from a nested array in MongoDB document using Express server, React, Redux on the REST API endpoint /plates/:plateId/comments.

To be able to get this done I need to pass the plateId to redux action, therefore endpoint will be something like /plates/5403546s45465d465465f/comments

here is my redux action:

```
/////////////////////////////////{ FETCH COMMENTS }/////////////////////////////////
export const fetchComments = (plateId) => (dispatch) =>{
    console.log(plateId)
    dispatch(commentsLoading(true));

    fetch(url + 'plates/' + plateId + '/comments')
    .then(res => {
        if(res.ok){
            return res;
        }else
        var error = new Error('Error ' + res.status + ' ' + res.statusText);
        throw error;
    }, error =>{
    var disconnected = new Error('Error ' + error.message + ' (fetchComments Cannot connect to the server)')
    throw disconnected
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(comments => dispatch(addComments(comments)))
    .catch(error => dispatch(commentsFailed(error.message)));
};
```

and in the main component I have:

```
    const mapStateToProps = state =>{
      return{
        plates: state.plates,
        comments: state.comments
      } 
    };
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
      fetchComments: (plateId) => { dispatch(fetchComments(plateId))},
      fetchPlates: () => { dispatch(fetchPlates())}
    });
     
    class Main extends Component {
    
      componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchPlates();
        this.props.fetchComments();
      };
    
      render(){
        
        const plateInfo = ({match}) =>{
          return(
            <DishDetail plate={this.props.plates.plates.filter((item) => item._id === match.params.plateId)[0]}
                        comments={this.props.comments.comments}
            />
          )
        }
        return (
              <div className="container">
                    <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/menu/:plateId" component={plateInfo} />
                    </Switch>
              </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    export default withRouter(connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Main));
```

I tried to pass fetchComments as props to dishDetail component in order to pass plateId argument as follow
**props.fetchComments(props.plate._id)**  but it doesn't work with the error message

> Cannot update a component (`Connect(Main)`) while rendering a
> different component (`DishDetail`).

Comment: What's the version of React-router you are using. You need to pass those props when you declare your routes. So the component will receive it as props.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your attention. React-router version is ^5.2.0, and yes I passed fetchComments to Dishdetail component through routes

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for reading my questions (without answering)

Anyway, after some attempts, I figured it out with this approach and I'm sharing my answer hopefully it will help someone in the future.

I changed my main class component to a functional component in order to use **useLocation** and **useEffect** hooks the best way.

and here is my new simpler code:

```
.......
.......

function Main (props) {
  const location = useLocation();
  var plateId = location.pathname.split('/')[2];
  
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchComments(plateId);
  }, [plateId && plateId !== undefined])

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchPlates();
    props.fetchStaff();
    props.fetchFeedback();
    // props.fetchFavorites();
  }, []);

   
    const plateInfo = ({match}) =>{
      return(
        <DishDetail plate={props.plates.plates.filter((item) => item._id === match.params.plateId)[0]}
........
......
......
......
export default withRouter(connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Main));
```